# Can someone marry a wife of his maternal uncle after the separation of that uncle and aunt?

Tags: halal-haram, nikah, mahram

I have read a lot of articles regarding this subject, but I couldn't find any solution to my problem. My question is,

Can someone marry a wife of his maternal uncle after the separation of that uncle and aunt?

Please back up your answer with credible sources.

Comment: Relevant http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/what-women-cant-a-man-marry?lq=1 http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/11174/which-relatives-are-haram-to-marry-in-islam?lq=1 ...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is permissible for a man to marry the divorced wife of his maternal uncle, if she has completed her [iddah period](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iddah). An uncle’s wife is not a close relative to whom marriage is prohibited, so there is nothing wrong with marrying her. Allah says in the Quran (interpretation of the meaning):

> حُرِّمَتْ عَلَيْكُمْ أُمَّهَٰتُكُمْ وَبَنَاتُكُمْ وَأَخَوَٰتُكُمْ
>   وَعَمَّٰتُكُمْ وَخَٰلَٰتُكُمْ وَبَنَاتُ ٱلْأَخِ وَبَنَاتُ ٱلْأُخْتِ
>   وَأُمَّهَٰتُكُمُ ٱلَّٰتِىٓ أَرْضَعْنَكُمْ وَأَخَوَٰتُكُم مِّنَ
>   ٱلرَّضَٰعَةِ وَأُمَّهَٰتُ نِسَآئِكُمْ وَرَبَٰٓئِبُكُمُ ٱلَّٰتِى فِى
>   حُجُورِكُم مِّن نِّسَآئِكُمُ ٱلَّٰتِى دَخَلْتُم بِهِنَّ فَإِن لَّمْ
>   تَكُونُوا۟ دَخَلْتُم بِهِنَّ فَلَا جُنَاحَ عَلَيْكُمْ وَحَلَٰٓئِلُ
>   أَبْنَآئِكُمُ ٱلَّذِينَ مِنْ أَصْلَٰبِكُمْ وَأَن تَجْمَعُوا۟ بَيْنَ
>   ٱلْأُخْتَيْنِ إِلَّا مَا قَدْ سَلَفَ ۗ إِنَّ ٱللَّهَ كَانَ غَفُورًا
>   رَّحِيمًا
>
> Prohibited to you (For marriage) are:- Your mothers, daughters,
>   sisters; father's sisters, Mother's sisters; brother's daughters,
>   sister's daughters; foster-mothers (Who gave you suck),
>   foster-sisters; your wives' mothers; your step-daughters under your
>   guardianship, born of your wives to whom ye have gone in,- no
>   prohibition if ye have not gone in;- (Those who have been) wives of
>   your sons proceeding from your loins; and two sisters in wedlock at
>   one and the same time, except for what is past; for Allah is
>   Oft-forgiving, Most Merciful;-

Comment: Unless, of course, there are no other prohibiting reasons.